# is it possible to use input() in the body of a function?

Tags: python, function, input

My students want to use input () inside a function.
Here is a sample student code, this is a simple calculator:

```
def calc():
    while(True):
        req=input(": ")
        if req=="":
            break
        print(req+"="+str(eval(req)))

calc()
```

I always thought that this is not done. Or I'm wrong?
Please help me figure it out. And if this is not done, please explain why

PS.we don't talk about return, just about using the input in the body of a function

Comment: It's fine to use `input` inside a function. The key is to decide *which* function `input` should be used in. It would be better to separate the pure computation from the "impure" I/O. And why are you delaying introducing `return`? That's a key part of using functions properly. (And *please*, do not introduce `eval` so early; you'll make your students think that the use of `eval` is common and safe.)

Comment: Parentheses around `True`? Meh, they're unnecessary but harmless. `eval`? Burn it with fire. Yes, parsing is probably beyond what they are doing now, but teaching them that it's OK to `eval` just because it's convenient will install *very* bad habits. Better to provide them with a proper focused function they can use in its place.

Comment: Thanks a lot! about the reterns - we are familiar with what the function returns. I see an error in this case, but the purpose of the discussion is different. principle of single responsibility))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put `input` calls inside a function body. It makes your function [impure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which is not ideal from a [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) point of view, but not every program must be functional.

Comment: Separating I/O from computation is beneficial even if you aren't using pure functions excusively.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! well, as I understood it is permissible. can someone give an example of a built-in function or from a library that has an input? I can't remember that. I would like to have an example to explain

Comment: and what's the point? if you need data, you create a parameter for it. so why do you need input() inside? even if you don't always need some data, you can assign the default parameter  None

Comment: [Here's an example from the standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/urllib/request.py#L2350). Yes, you can re-write programs that use `input` inside functions so that they don't, and sometimes that is a good idea, but not always. For one, you're likely to end up with a mess of top-level `input` calls in all but the simplest cases. These should all be in `main` at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

As the other comments already stated, there is no problem in using `input` inside a function.

**Note:** Other people mention functional programming, but if you're teaching Python and especially `input`, I highly doubt this will have any impact on your course as Python is OOP at its core and functional programming may confuse your students.